# ASP.NET MVC can't create additional fields in the table, Simplemembership

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, simplemembership

I have a problem with simplemembership and tables.
I create a user by WebSecurity, with the `CreateUserAndAccount` method.

```
 WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(registerdata.Username, registerdata.Password, new { Email = registerdata.Email, Age = registerdata.Age, Country = registerdata.Country, NativeLanguage=registerdata.NativeLanguage, LanguageToLearn=registerdata.LanguageToLearn });
```

But it has an error when I run the app because I don't have the additional fields in the table.

```
   WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("ChatContext", "Users", "UserID", "Username",autoCreateTables:true);
```

Can I add these fields to an existing table by using code first? I create a context:

```
  public class ChatContext : DbContext
{
    public ChatContext(): base("ChatContext")
    {          
    }
    public DbSet<UserModel> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<VoteModel> Votes { get; set; }
}
```

UserModel:

```
   [Table("Users")]
public class UserModel
{
    [Key]
    public string UserID { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string NativeLanguage { get; set; }
    public string LanguageToLearn { get; set; }
    public float  Vote { get; set; }
}
```

Application_Start()

```
        protected void Application_Start()
    {            
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        Database.SetInitializer(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<ChatContext>());
        WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("ChatContext", "Users", "UserID", "Username",autoCreateTables:true);            
    }
```

Unfortunately, the tables are not created.
Can someone explain me how I can add these additional fields in the user table?

Answer (score 0):

If you have table "Users" in database you should do migration for adding fields to database [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj193542(v=vs.113).aspx?f=255&mspperror=-2147217396#Anchor_5][1]

And if you want use table "Users", which exists in your database - change from `autoCreateTables:true` to `autoCreateTables:false` in method "WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection".

But if you don't have "Users" in db then try

> WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("ChatContext", "Users",
>   "UserID", "Username",autoCreateTables:true);

and if table was created then check fields and do migration if needed.

Comment: More about Migration https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn579398.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396